# Can I pass to the limit?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let be a sequence $u_n$ of $C_0^\infty (\mathbb{R}^N)$-functions converging to $u$ in $H^1(\mathbb{R}^N)$, which implies that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$ and   $\nabla u_n\rightarrow \nabla u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, such that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} div\ (\vert u_n(x)\vert ^2 x)\ dx \rightarrow 0 $$ and I wonder if I can say that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N} div\ (\vert u _n(x)\vert ^2 x)\ dx \rightarrow     \int_{\mathbb{R}^N} div\ (\vert u (x)\vert ^2 x)\ dx=0   $$
Note that $$div (|u(x)|^2x) =    \nabla|u(x)|^2x+|u(x)|^2div(x)=(\overline{u}(x)\nabla u(x)+u(x)\nabla             \overline{u}(x) )\cdot x +N   |u(x)|^2  $$
I need some help or hint here, please. I have never seen a rigurous proof by density. Clearly, by the fact that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^N)$, one has $$ N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N }   |u_n(x)|^2 \rightarrow N\int_{\mathbb{R}^N }   |u(x)|^2 $$ but I need help por the other part $    
(\overline{u}(x)\nabla u(x)+u(x)\nabla             \overline{u}(x))\cdot x  $

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this not just continuity of the inner product in $L^2$?

Comment: I dont see it clearly.. can you explain a little bit?

Comment: For example,  $<u_n,<\nabla u_n, x>>$ tends to $<u,<\nabla u, x>>$ by continuity of inner product in L^2?